# Locate an element using another element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to store an element in a string variable, but in order to locate the element I need another element to meet a condition. The reason I need to don't want to go directly to the intended element is because there are multiple similar elements on the page, and I need the element text associated with a specific title.

Basically, if element1 = x, find element2 associated with element1

The HTML is:

```html
<div class="ItemPage-stickerTitle" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Spirit | 2020 RMR</div>
<div class="ItemPage-stickerValue">Sticker price: $0.04</div>
<div class="ItemPage-stickerStatus">Slot 1 - Unscratched</div>
```

What I want is this:

If the stickerTitle = 'x', then stickerStatus = 'text in sticker status class'

The only thing I have tried is

```
sticker_wear = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@ItemPage-stickerTitle = excel_output.at[URL_Price_num, 'Sticker'] and @ItemPage-stickerStatus]").text
```

Which I know is not correct. Would greatly appreciate some help on this.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant HTML as text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you are looking for. You just need to set `title` to whatever the title of the vehicle is.

```
title = "Spirit | 2020 RMR"
sticker_wear = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='ItemPage-stickerTitle'][text()='{title}']/following-sibling::div[@class='ItemPage-stickerStatus']").text
```

Comment: This worked! So I'm guessing the /following-sibling is the best way to go in cases like this?

Comment: It depends... it's what was necessary in this case to find the element you needed.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like something that should be done in the logic of the python program.

```
if element1 == 'text':
    stringvariable = element2.text
```

Is there a reason you can't do this? It seems you are already most of the way there.

Comment: `element1` is never going to equal 'text' since it's not a string, it's a `WebElement`. How do you find `element2`?